# Dumping db schema using DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader

Tags: oracle, perl, dbix-class

I want to [dump db schema](https://metacpan.org/release/JROBINSON/DBIx-Class-Tutorial-0.0001/view/lib/DBIx/Class/Tutorial/Part1.pod) so I can later use it with `DBIx:Class`.

Connection itself is apparently ok, however there are complaints about moniker clashes that I've tried to resolve by using `naming => {ALL=>'v8', force_ascii=>1}`

```
perl -MDBIx::Class::Schema::Loader=make_schema_at,dump_to_dir:./lib -E "$|++;make_schema_at('EC::Schema', { debug => 1, naming => {ALL=>'v8', force_ascii=>1} }, [ 'dbi:Oracle:', 'XX/PP@TNS' ])"
```

output (ending up without content in `./lib`)

```
Bad table or view 'V_TRANSACTIONS', ignoring: DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader::DBI::_sth_for(): DBI Exception: DBD::Oracle::db prepare failed: ORA-04063: view "ss.vv" has errors (DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator at char 22 in 'SELECT * FROM ..

Unable to load schema - chosen moniker/class naming style results in moniker clashes. Change the naming style, or supply an explicit moniker_map: tables "ss"."AQ$_PRARAC_ASY_QUEUE_TABLE_S", "ss"."AQ$PRARAC_ASY_QUEUE_TABLE_S" reduced to the same source moniker 'AqDollarSignPraracAsyQueueTableS';
```

Any suggestions how to solve clashes or use some other dump schema method are welcome.